# How do I find the most parent SuperView?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, superview

I'm trying to add a new subView to a page, such that everything but itself is greyed out. However, I'm calling it from within a subview of the screen. To get it out, I have to do the following :

```
[self.view.superview.superview.superview.superview addSubview:self.cardDialog.view];
```

As you can surmise, this is extremely bad code. How can I find the proper parent level and set it correctly?

Comment: How do you define the proper parent? The `window`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the view is part of the view hierarchy, use the `window` property.

```
UIView* topView = self.view.window;
```

Or if your view is not on screen yet, you can get the window indirectly through your app delegate

```
UIView* topView = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
```

Else, if your target is *not* the window, you can walk up the view hierarchy until you find the view you want:

```
UIView* topView = self.view;

while(topView.superview != nil){
    topview = topView.superview;

    if( /*topview is the one you were looking for*/ ){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless the view isn't on screen yet, `self.view.window` does the same thing.

Comment: And it's unlikely the OP is really looking for the window. The question is a big unclear.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I assumed the window was the end goal

Comment: @Wain good point. I added the case if the view is not yet part of the hierarchy

Comment: @michaels Wain's point is that your `while` loop can all be replaced with that one line - `self.view.window`.

Comment: I'm getting nil with view.window

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself on this situation once and I gave up. I decided to use a modalView instead with a cross disolve transition. Not only you avoid the problem you are having but it helps keeping things organized.
Lately I improved this aproach by grabing a snapshot of the parentVC and sending it to the modalView, then I apply a tint. The overall effect is exactly what you are looking for, I guess.